# JavaScript variable name in ISO 8859-1 or Unicode

Tags: javascript, variables, unicode, iso

JavaScript documentations [states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Variables): `Starting with JavaScript 1.5, you can use ISO 8859-1 or Unicode letters such as å and ü in identifiers.`

So I tried this out:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>JavaScript index</title>
    <script>

    var ü = 'tom';

    console.log( ü );

    </script>
</head>
</html>
```

Console returns an: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Yes I am in a browser environment: Chrome 40

Why is this an error?

Comment: It works fine in my chrome 40

Comment: Same, works fine for me.

Comment: OK I updated the code to include the HTML. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't indicate to the browser what encoding the HTML file was to be parsed with. You should add a `<meta charset="..."/>` element in the start of the `<head>` to let it know what encoding you've saved it as. (I suggest using UTF-8.)

From the error I suspect you saved the file as UTF-8, but without the `meta` element the browser has arbitrarily guessed the file is in Windows code page 1252 (Western European). The character `ü` encoded to UTF-8 is the byte sequence 0xC3, 0xBC. That byte sequence mis-decoded as cp1252 is `Ã¼`, which is an ILLEGAL variable name because `¼` is not a letter.

Comment: Thanks. That did the trick and was the problem. I added the UTF-8 encoding. Where did you get this information from, about the `cp1252 and the necessary inclusion of the meta tag`? Just curious so that in the future I can better solve problems.

Comment: @samyismyhero The encoding of text files is largely arbitrary and without a header that specifies it in unconditional terms, it's open to interpretation. The `<meta>` tag is how HTML does it. XML has a similar trick.

Comment: And code page 1252 is the most common guessed encoding for browsers running in an English or other Western European locale. When you've seen UTF-8-misinterpreted-as-Western-European mojibake enough times they are obvious. Other outcomes are possible because the story of how browsers go about guessing encodings in the face of missing charset-indicator is a long and complex one indeed.